# How to redirect to an angular view from server-side routing?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, routes

I would like to do something like this:

```
res.render('profile.ejs',{data:data});
```

but using angular. In other words, I have a view `home#/profile`,
with data-binding to `$scope.data`.

Now, I need to have the server side routing redirect the call to the profile view, and send data at the same time (I use this when the user confirms their email).

Is there a way to call a specific view from the server-side routing, and populate the `$scope.data` in the client-side controller? 
Thanks!

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your problem. tell me what should be done in specific way step-wise.

Comment: I can try to summarize the main point of my question this way: how can I redirect to a specific view from server-side routing? Is there a way to do something like res.redirect('/home#/profile'), where profile is an angular view?